# Angularfire2 child_added event is returning all data everytime child fires

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

How to get only child_added data in angularfire2. i know that this question has been already asked. but there is not any acceptable answer. reference [child_added event reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113599/angularfire2-child-added-event-return-all-data-again)

how can i fetch only new data when function is called.

I have angularfire2 5.0.0-rc.3 installed in my angular project.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.